# Как использовать X509Certificate2 от пользователя?

Tags: c#

Доброе время суток. Подскажите, написал небольшую программу для установки сертификатов УЦ в корневые и промежуточные центры, программа вылетает при попытке установки сертификата.

> Подробная информация об использовании оперативной  (JIT) отладки
>   вместо данного диалогового  окна содержится в конце этого сообщения.
>
> ************** Текст исключения ************** System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Отказано в
>   доступе

Пользователь только в группе "Пользователи"

```
// установка сертификатов:
// минкомсвязи
var thumbprint = Regex.Replace("4b c6 dc 14 d9 70 10 c4 1a 26 e0 58 ad 85 1f 81 c8 42 41 5a", @"[^\da-zA-z]", string.Empty).ToUpper();

using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

    if (certificates.Count > 0)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Сертификат Минкомсвязи уже установлен");
        System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\4BC6DC14D97010C41A26E058AD851F81C842415A.cer");
    }
    else
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\4BC6DC14D97010C41A26E058AD851F81C842415A.cer");
        store.Add(certificate); 
        store.Close();
        System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\4BC6DC14D97010C41A26E058AD851F81C842415A.cer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовали запускать программу от имени администратора?

Comment: От имени администратора тоже самое пишет.

Comment: Значит запустите от того пользователя, у которого есть права

Comment: вручную любой пользователь может поставить сертификат, почему это не удается сделать при использовании X509Certificate2

Comment: 1. Хотелось бы увидить `stack trace` ошибки. 2. Возможно дело не в самом серитфекате, а в пути, где он находится (доступу к нему)

Comment: как-куда его лучше загрузить ? нужен полный текст когда программа вылетает? его?